# Are These Oyster Crabs?

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

I found these crabs at the end of September, 2018. My family was vacationing on the coast of Lopez Island in the Pacific Ocean off of Washington State. I have been trying to figure out what they are ever since.

I found two crabs, one that was orange and black, and another crab that was off-white and black. They are both about an inch and a half across and an inch from front to back. I did some research and the closest match I could find are oyster crabs, which are found inside oysters on the East Coast of North America (I found my information on oyster crabs [here](https://www.pangeashellfish.com/blog/what-are-pea-crabs-and-why-are-they-in-my-oysters)).

However, I found these inside *clams* on the *West Coast*. Also, the pictures of oyster crabs I can find online (figure 1) do not look like my oyster crabs. I was wondering if anyone can identify these crabs. Sorry about the picture quality and thanks in advance!

[image: A picture of an oyster crab I found online]
[Figure 1: A picture of an oyster crab that I found online. There are not very many pictures of oyster crabs online, and they all look similar to this one.]

[image: Two supposed oyster crabs]
[Figure 2: The back of the two supposed oyster crabs I found. They are not fighting, I just put them close together for the picture.]

[image: The front of one supposed oyster crab]
[Figure 3: The front of the off-white supposed oyster crab. In the picture, you can see its tiny eyes and small mouth, along with the claws.]

[image: The front of another supposed oyster crab]
[Figure 4: The front of the orange supposed oyster crab. In the picture, you can see its tiny eyes, small mouth, and claws.]

[image: The back of the orange supposed oyster crab]
[Figure 5: The back of the orange supposed oyster crab.]

[image: The back of the off-white supposed oyster crab]
[Figure 6: The back of the off-white supposed oyster crab.]

[image: The undersides of the supposed oyster crabs]
[Figure 7: The undersides of the two supposed oyster crabs. As you can see, they both have eight legs and two claws, making them crabs and part of the crustacean family.]

Answer (score 1):

What you have found are pea crabs, which have a fascinating life history of parasitism. https://www.whitestoneoysters.com/blogs/an-oyster-life/what-the-shuck-is-a-pea-crab

Comment: Thanks for answering this question! We appreciate when new users with expert knowledge begin answering questions! Please update your post, however, to include more information about *why* your ID is correct. Given the propensity for external links to go defunct, we ask that your answer *here* can adequately stand on its own in explaining both the correct answer and your rationale. Support as a link is fine (and citing/linking sources is preferred/required), but please capture some of the relevant detail from your external source in your post itself. Thanks!